# I want to show the number of rows that come from paginator : zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

I want to show the number of rows that come from paginator : zend framework

Example:

number  | productname  |   price
**1.**  |     pen      |       25.00
 
**2.**  |     Pencil   |      10.00
**3.**  |     Booklet  |       12.00

I want to show the number of rows as the number of rows. Shown in the example.

thank for answer